How to do forever anonymous authentication with realm?
I'm trying to build an "offline first" react native app. Basically the user can use the app without signing up, but can later decide to sign up to sync data across all devices.
I went for realm but it looks like an anonymous users (inactive) could be deleted after 90 days. As far as I see it, a user could decide to never sign up.
What is the suggested approach to handle this scenario?

If it's "offline-first" then it shouldn't need to communicate with MongoDB-Atlas at all. Just use local-storage.

It's "offline first" not "offline forever". What if the user decides to sign up to sync data on the cloud? Should I use local storage by default, and then on sign up dump local to cloud and switch to cloud?

Those are not mutually-exclusive options: methinks you'd always be using local-storage for the benefit of users who are temporarily offline or who have spotty/poor internet connections, and as a local staging area prior to pushing to your non-local storage.

Local staging is handled by realm once user is authenticated. Should I add local storage (eg RxDB) on top of that when user is not authenticated?

Allowing users to continually use the app online, anonymous auth is going to cost you a significant amount of money. If you're independently wealthy then thats very generous of you but if not, you'll need a revenue stream to offset the costs. The free tier runs out of room pretty quickly with multiple users. You should only use local storage as a free indefinitely app and when they sign up and pay, then activate online for all their online device data sharing experience.
